# jquery: How to Get value from array of JSON Object by another value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get value from JSON Object by another value
my code:

```
var ar=[{"one","a"},{"two","b"},{"three","c"},{"four","d"}];
```

I want to do something like this without using loops:

```
var val=ar["c"];   // i want result=three
```

Comment: That isn't valid JSON or JavaScript.

Comment: Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) to see how to parse JSON.

Comment: @Zosimas: Which is fine, but irrelevant; there's no JSON here.

Comment: I agree @T.J.Crowder, but I thought it would help. ;)

Comment: @Zosimas eeek. W3schools is a terrible resource. Concerning that specific page - they are suggesting `eval` - this is problematic if you care about performance or if you can't trust the source. Don't just use `eval`! They even present it as the preferred way to parse JSON (page 2). "Can be parsed using built-in JavaScript eval()" is definitely not a benefit. "Uses arrays" - uhh... what?"Data is in name/value pairs" - not correct. Object elements are k/v pairs. Their comparison to JS assignnments is just confusing. The entire site lacks code indentation. They scarcely use semicolons. Page 4:WAT

Comment: Page four of that tutorial makes me physically unwell and I sincerely hope no-one _ever_ will follow that tutorial. I sincerely hope no-one ever will even _see_ the page. `eval` is BAD. Use `JSON.parse`. Even jQuery runs the JSON through some basic Regex tests before resorting to `eval`. Since IE7 is the last to not support `JSON`, jQuery 2.0 does not even contain that fallback at all. A tiny lightbulb at the end of the paragraph doesn't cut it. They should show the `JSON.parse` method first, then say it doesn't work in IE, then show why eval is bad, then how to use it correctly (with checks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you actually have an array of arrays. And you are not changing it. You can convert this array into object.

```
var ar=[ ["one","a"], ["two","b"] , ["three","c"], ["four","d"] ];

var cache = (function(arr){
    var cache = {};
    arr.forEach(function(item){cache[item[1]] = item[0]});
    return cache;
}(ar));
cache["c"]; //"three"
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: it is not possible. Looping is the only way to retrieve if you only have the data structure you posted.

So the best solution is writing a function that loops over the object and returns the value. That way you can easily access it whenever you need it without writing the loop each time. However, it's O(n) for obvious reasons.

Comment: And that's if you assume some valid version of the data structure, which as posted isn't.

Comment: Or you can loop once, create a hash, and use it later to find any property in O(1) time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are typos above, and that you meant to write:

```
var ar=[ ["one","a"], ["two","b"] , ["three","c"], ["four","d"] ];
```

If you can live with IE 9 and up, or other modern browsers, `array.filter()` can help:

```
function findMatch( ar, key ) {
  var matches = ar.filter(
    function( el ) {
      return (el[1] == key);  // match against the second element of each member
    }
  );

  if (matches.length > 0)
    return( matches[0][0] );  // return the first element of the first match
  else 
    return null;
}

var val = findMatch( ar, "c" );
```

For earlier browsers, a DIY version of `filter` is included here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible without loops, just not the the best way,

assuming that your array is in that order with the object progression as abc..
and the keys are in lowercase a to z

```
var ar=[{"one" : "a"},{"two" : "b"},{"three" : "c"},{"four" : "d"}];

var key = ("c".charCodeAt(0) - 97);

var val = Object.keys(ar[key])[0];
```

**note, depending on the JS engine processing this code, you may or may not get your answer since the first item in the object is not the same as one would think.
by this, I mean, an object is not ordered

EDIT: I forgot to fix your objects, here's the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/rJ7j9/